# Color de fondo sale mal en la tercera iteración - c# consola

Tags: c#

haber si alguien pueda ayudarme, tengo el siguiente código que funciona bien en la entrega de resultado, pero en la presentación del color de fondo sale mal, a partir de la 3ra iteración, el color de fondo verde se agrega en la siguiente línea. ¿a que se debe?

```
string op;
do{

Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
Console.WriteLine("\n«« MENU - ACTIVIDAD NRO 1 »»");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] Ejercicio {i}");
Console.WriteLine("[11] Salir \n");
Console.Write("Presione [numero] correspondiente, para ejecutar el ejercicio: ");
op = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";

switch(op){
    case "1":
        //ejecutarPrograma1();
        break;
    case "2":
        //ejecutarPrograma2();
        break;    
    default:
        break;
}

}while(op != "11");
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: Captura del Resultado]

Comment: ¿Qué tal si lo haces con `Console.Write`? Los pasos ahora serían así: 1. Cambia el color. 2. Escribe en consola con `Write` solamente. 3. Vuelve a cambiar el color. 4. Si necesitas introducir un salto de línea ahora sí llama a `WriteLine`, `Write('\n')` o como prefieras.

Answer (score 1):

No es que a la 3ra iteración pase eso, pasa cuando se llega al final de la pantalla y la consola hace scroll (lo puedes probar maximizando la consola y verás que posiblemente esto te pasa ahora a la 4ta iteración), esto sucede porque el texto se desplaza una línea hacia arriba y el repintado se hace solo de la porción de texto, no del espacio en blanco que queda hacia la derecha.

Una posible solución es que a cada línea le agregues espacios en blanco hasta llegar a la derecha, para que el repintado sea a lo largo de la línea.

```
Ejercicio 1[espacio][espacio][espacio][espacio]....[espacio]
```

Para esto puedes crear una función que imprima una línea completa

```
public static void Print(string text)
=>  Console.WriteLine(text + string.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat(" ",Console.BufferWidth - text.Length)));
```

Esto funcionaria para un texto que ocupe una líneas o menos. Para un texto largo, que ocupara más de una línea habría que hacer algo más elaborado:

```
public static void Print(string text="")
=>  Console.WriteLine(text + 
    string.Join("",
        Enumerable.Repeat(" ",
            Console.BufferWidth >= text.Length ? Console.BufferWidth - text.Length :
            Console.BufferWidth - text.Length % Console.BufferWidth
            )
        )
    );
```

Te dejo un código completo, con algunos otros cambios

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var operacion = MostrarMenu();
            Ejecutar(operacion)?.Invoke();
        }

    }
    public static string MostrarMenu()
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Write("\n«« MENU - ACTIVIDAD NRO 1 »»"); 
        Console.ResetColor();
        Print();
           
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Print($"[{i}] Ejercicio {i}");
        Console.WriteLine("[11] Salir \n");
        Console.Write("Presione [numero] correspondiente, para ejecutar el ejercicio: ");
        return Console.ReadLine()!;
    }

    public static Action? Ejecutar(string op) => op switch
    {
        "1" => ejecutarPrograma1,
        "2" => ejecutarPrograma2,
        "11" => () => Environment.Exit(0),
        _ => null
    };


    public static void Print(string text="")
    =>  Console.WriteLine(text + 
        string.Join("",
            Enumerable.Repeat(" ",
                Console.BufferWidth >= text.Length ? Console.BufferWidth - text.Length :
                Console.BufferWidth - text.Length % Console.BufferWidth
                )
            )
        );
        
    public static void ejecutarPrograma1() { }
    public static void ejecutarPrograma2() { }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono tu recomendación.

Answer (score 0):

Si se cambia el color luego de imprimir, según el color previo a la llamada, y luego se añade un retorno de carro, se evita exactamente eso, y se mantiene el scroll igualmente.

Utiliza para eso, este metodo en lugar de WriteLine();

Usa este codigo para evitar eso:

```
ConsoleColor backgroundC;
ConsoleColor foregroungC; 

private void printLine(string cline)
  {
  ConsoleColor currentBackgC=Console.BackgroundColor;
  ConsoleColor currentForeC=Console.ForegroundColor;

   if (backgroundC == null)
       backgroundC = currentBackC;
   if (foregroundC == null)
       foregroundC = currentForeC;

     Condole.Write(cline);

         Console.ForegroundColor = foregroundC;
         Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundC;
         Console.Write("\n");
         
  foregrundC = currentForeC;
  backgroundC = currentBackC;
  return;
  }
```

De las dos propuestas que aporto por aqui, esta primera, es la que me gusta más, porque mantiene netamente el comportamiento de Console.WriteLine(); previniendo hacer scroll con retorno de carro del mismo color por error.

Ademas, es el codigo mas directo, que cambia solo lo que se trata.

Otra posibilidad de evitar eso, es evitar que haga el scroll, sin desactivarlo, utilizando un metodo, como el siguiente, en lugar de utilizar Console.WriteLine(string Text);

Cuando quede una linea para completar el alto, esperara a que pulses una tecla, y limpiará/borrará la pantalla.

Ten en cuenta que solo te va a dejar meter un retorno de carro por linea.

Evita poner retornos de carro `\n` con colores de los que no quieras lineas extra, y listo.

```
private void  writeOneLine(string oneline)
     {
     string ret="\n";       
     if (oneline!=ret)
      if (oneline.Contains(ret)   
       oneline = oneline.Remove(oneline.IndexOf(ret)+ret.Length);
                  
    Console.WriteLine(oneline);
    if (Console.CursorTop()>=Console.WindowsHeigth-1)
     {
     if ((Console.CursorTop()==Console.WindowsHeigth-1)
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
     Console.Write("[Pulse una tecla para continuar..]");
     Console.ReadKey(true);
     Console.Clear();                         
     Console.SetCursorPosition(1,1);
     }                                                                     
   return;
   }
```